# Posting to Facebook page's wall via Python 3, token problems

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I think my issue centers around Facebook tokens.

I have my personal Facebook account.  For my project I created a Project App and a Project Page under this account.

I can get a token that doesn't expire, no problem.  BUT, using Python 3 and the "facebook" package I can only seem to post two ways:

1) If I use graph.put_object(AppID, "feed", message='Automated post!') it will post onto the Project Page from my personal account, not as the Project Page itself.

2) If I use graph.put_wall_post(message='Automated post!') it will post onto my personal page as myself.

What I want to do is post to my project page as my project page.  I think the tokens I have are wrong.  I'm aware of the Graph Explorer and the Access Token Debugger but can't find a clear explanation of how to get a token that will let me post to the page I own (not my personal page) as that page itself (not as me).  Help, and thank you!

Comment: this may help you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: That looks like what I was hoping to find, thank you!

Comment: Actually I'm still not getting something right.  I walked through those steps and got the token that should let me post to the page as the page, and made it a long-lasting token.  When I try to use it to post programmatically (from Python 3) I get an error: "facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Comment: then make sure the token includes the publish_pages permission

Comment: It does, I verified repeatedly (for the app - If there's a way to do this for the page then that may be the magic sauce I'm missing). /tableflip